# Xamarin custom Grid View with automatic column and row Definitions

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to extend `Grid` and implement an automatic row and column handling and indexing based on the amount of children added in XAML. So I only have to define the rows and columns and then the view is basically filled up with the children in the order they are listed in xaml.

I extended `Grid` as follows

```
namespace Foo.Controls
{
    public class KeyValueGrid : Grid
    {
        public KeyValueGrid() : base()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"KeyValueGrid() We have {Children.Count} childs.");
        }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            // rebuild row and col defs based on this.Children
        }
    }
}
```

However, the method `OnInitialized()` has been removed/obsolete. Is there any way to tell that the View has been constructed completely from XAML?

The table/grid I'm trying to achieve looks simply like this:

```
|----------------------------------------------|
|         Section Caption                      |
|----------------------------------------------|
|                 Key | Value                  |
|----------------------------------------------|
|                 Key | Value                  |
|----------------------------------------------|
|          ...        |                        |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: From what you are describing, FlexLayout does not match what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Might be, yeah. I didn't know FlexLayout. Is there a way to tell FlexLayout to have two columns or wrap after every other child? (I edited the question and added a ascii style table of what I'm trying to achieve)

Comment: You can play with it using the samples projects available here https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/FlexLayoutDemos/

Comment: Another "simple" solution, would be to create a simple ListView, with a cell template matching your layout requirements for Key and Value. You can then use the Header property of your ListView, to create what you describe as "Section Caption"